# Order on MySQL is Returning 1,11,2,22 not 1,2,11,22

Tags: php, sorting, mysqli

On this MySQL Query the ordering is sorting all results digit by digit. What I want is to simply return the smallest number first. Am I going about this wrong, or is it just the way PHP sorts?

MySQL:

```
$history = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,credits,timeadded FROM users ORDER by credits ASC);
```

**Returned Result (Credits only):**

1,13,14,16,2,24,29,3,31

**Desired Result:**

1,2,3,13,14,16,24,29,31

Comment: what is the data type of credits ?

Comment: credits is varchar or integer?

Comment: I think data type of credits is not int, or just try CAST http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `credits` column must be a string. So MySQL use string comparison to order your results. And, when you compare, for example, `11` and `2` strings, `2` is 'bigger' than `11` (2 is a bigger char than 1).

You should to something like this :

```
SELECT id,credits,timeadded FROM users ORDER by CAST(credits AS UNSIGNED)
```

Then MySQL will make the comparison considering credits as a number : `11` will be bigger than `2`.

BTW, if you only store numbers into this column, why it is VARCHAR type ? 
You can change it with an `ALTER TABLE` statement :

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY credits INTEGER;
```

Comment: It always makes me wonder why people overupvoting answers like this - causing unavoidable fullscan/filesort.

Comment: I told him to change the column type if he's able to. I even put the statement to do it. What is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is not with your answer, but with votes.

Comment: BTW, I just found this [very interesting article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html). MySQL uses indexes for sorting in only two cases : if the column in order by clause is indexed or if it is used in where clause. Even the use of two indexed columns makes MySQL to do a filesort. But not always a fullscan.

Comment: One don't need no article to tell that sorting by a function result is a big no-no.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by OlivierH

> Your credits column must be a string. So MySQL use string comparison
>   to order your results.

Modify your table so that 'credtis' column will be INT or as needed but still a number so MySql will treat it as such and will return results as you want them (sorted numerically not by string comparison)